# jquery check if radio is checked or if is being checked

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="on">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="off">
```

I need to display #textbox only if #radio1 is selected (first pageload). Or #radio2 is selected on first page load and the user clicks #radio2 the textbox should also show.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: How you mean *'first page load?'* is there usually more than one page load? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, can you explain in some more?

Comment: when do you hide the textbox?

Comment: @TheSystemRestart. I believe he meant show his value.

Comment: It's for a settings page. If the user has previously set it "on" then that radio will be selected and the textbox displayed.

Comment: What's with the downvotes lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/izugob/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
if( $('input#radio1').is(':checked') ){
  $('#textbox').show();
}

$('input#radio1, input#radio2').on('change',function(){
   $('#textbox').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you want right:

```
$(function(){
    if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')){ // if the radio1 is checked when the page
        alert($('#textbox').val());   //  was loaded, display textbox value
    }

    $('#radio2').click(function(){  // When the radio2 is clicked
        alert($('#textbox').val()); // show textbox value.
    });
});
```

Comment: I wanted to hide/show the textbox, but thanks, I can do it myself from here. Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#radio1').on('click', function() {
      if(this.checked) {
         $('#textbox').show();
      } else $('#textbox').hide();
    }).click();  // firing a initial click

    $('#radio2').on('click', function() {
         $('#textbox').show();
    });
});
```